# Is the html obfuscation really an effective anti-hacking mechanism?

Tags: html, forms, obfuscation, malware

Talking about html forms, does the html obfuscation really works?

Some post on SO says it's really a loss of time, because a talented "hacker" will always find the way to access your form fields (ex. associating Labels to inputs).

Has anybody implemented obfuscation and actually suffered an attack?

I would like to have your opinion about this subject.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: use a captcha and you'll be safe

Comment: but adding a captcha does not prevent a malware to manipulate the form data. no?

Comment: doesn't really matter if it can't submit it ;)

Comment: but the malware can always manipulate the data after the user has entered the captcha and submitted the form, right?

Comment: If your end user's host system is infected it's going to get very difficult to prevent an attack. It's basically the same as having a gun man next to him, a captcha won't help then ether. It is ( sadly ) the responsibility of the end user to make sure he doesn't get infected, preferably with a virus scanner of some sort. If an infected host system is not an acceptable risk you should look into advanced two factor authentication mechanisms, like most banks do ( a challenge response device etc...)

Comment: I understand the challenge response mechanism as a mechanism you could present the user the confirmation page asking him the password before "commiting" the transaction; but after he has validated the data the browser has sent, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14996/discussion-between-helmus-and-andresoviedo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obfuscation can't prevent any hacking, at it's best it's slowing down the process.

Especially with forms - the attacker can just take a look into his webconsole, examine your requests and then forge his own request accordingly.

The only real secure method is checking every incoming request serverside, since your server (hopefully) can't be compromised.

Thus, obfuscating HTML just proves that the author "is a noob" for trusting such a method.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to be a "talented hacker" to see the HTML source un-obfuscated. It's enough to know how to install a browser e.g. Chrome and use the code inspector. The code inspector presents a nice formatted HTML in any case – since it reads in the DOM, not some mangled raw text.

HTML obfuscation is an obstacle of which I do not see any benefits.